# argparse function arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I am trying to use argparse to create my script with parameters but I am not being able to.

The name of my script is `pipeline` and it has some options arguments like -b, -c, -i and -r.

If you call the script `./pipeline -b` should give an error asking for a git repository path but I am not being able to do this.

```
from git import Repo
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import argparse

class Ci:

    def build(self,args):
        cloned_repo = Repo.clone_from(args)
        print("clonning repository " + args)
        cloned_repo

        dir = git.split('/')(-1)

        if os.path.isdir(dir):
            print("repository cloned successfully")
        else:
            print("error to clone repository")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('-b','-build',action='store_true', help='execute mvn clean install')
    parser.add_argument('-c','-compress',action='store_true',help='zip a directory recursively')
    parser.add_argument('-i','-integration',action='store_true',help='execute mvn verify')
    parser.add_argument('-r','-release',action='store_true',help='execute build,integration and compress respectively')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.b:
        a = Ci()
        a.build()

    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        parser.print_help()
        sys.exit(1)
```

I can't make this sub-parameter work and I can't find a way to pass this parameter to my `build` function.

e.g:

```
./pipeline -b

Output: error missins git path
./pipeline -b https://git/repo
Output: clonning repo
```

and the string `"https://git/repo"` has to be passed as the argument to my  `build` function:

How can I make it work?

Comment: As a side note, I would use [docopt](http://docopt.org/) instead of argparse.

Comment: Indent your code properly please

Comment: @Romize. looks interesting. Seems simpler to use than argparse but I have a gut feeling that it won't be able to handle the very complex cases as well.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, we get these occasional recommendations to use other parsers, but never any code to show that they work better in the particular problem at hand.

Comment: When you present code that doesn't 'work', we expect you to tell us what was wrong - any error messages or results that don't match your expectations.  A vague 'don't work' isn't good enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first a note about convention: usually the longer option name is preceded by two hyphens like this `'--build'`

second, `'store_true'` is the action you perform with `'-b'`, which means argparse doesnt expect an argument after it, it just sets the `args.build` variable to `True` (and if the argument wasn't there it would set it to `False`)

try removing the `action='store_true'` and then it will default to storing the next value it finds in the argument list into `args.build`

Answer (score 1):

Reducing your code to:

```
import argparse

class Ci:

    def build(self,args):
        print("clonning repository " + args)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('-b','-build',action='store_true', help='execute mvn clean install')
    parser.add_argument('-c','-compress',action='store_true',help='zip a directory recursively')
    parser.add_argument('-i','-integration',action='store_true',help='execute mvn verify')
    parser.add_argument('-r','-release',action='store_true',help='execute build,integration and compress respectively')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args)

    if args.b:
        a = Ci()
        a.build()
```

I get:

```
1313:~/mypy$ python3 stack49408644.py -b
Namespace(b=True, c=False, i=False, r=False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack49408644.py", line 22, in <module>
    a.build()
TypeError: build() missing 1 required positional argument: 'args'
```

The parser runs fine, seeing `args.b` to `True`.  But the call to `build` is wrong.  It does not match the method's definition.

Providing a 'directory' doesn't help either, because `-b` is `True/False`

```
1313:~/mypy$ python3 stack49408644.py -b foo
usage: stack49408644.py [-h] [-b] [-c] [-i] [-r]
stack49408644.py: error: unrecognized arguments: foo
```

You need to either change `-b` to take an value, or add another argument that takes a value.

@AntiMatterDynamite showed how to change `-b`.  Instead let's add:

```
parser.add_argument('adir', help='a directory for build')
```

and change the `build` call

```
    a.build(args.adir)
```

Now the value is passed on to the method:

```
1322:~/mypy$ python3 stack49408644.py -b
usage: stack49408644.py [-h] [-b] [-c] [-i] [-r] adir
stack49408644.py: error: the following arguments are required: adir
1322:~/mypy$ python3 stack49408644.py -b foo
Namespace(adir='foo', b=True, c=False, i=False, r=False)
clonning repository foo
```

Instead redefining `-b`:

```
parser.add_argument('-b','-build', help='execute mvn clean install')

if args.b is not None:
    a = Ci()
    a.build(args.b)
```

test runs:

```
1322:~/mypy$ python3 stack49408644.py -b
usage: stack49408644.py [-h] [-b B] [-c] [-i] [-r]
stack49408644.py: error: argument -b/-build: expected one argument
1324:~/mypy$ python3 stack49408644.py -b foo
Namespace(b='foo', c=False, i=False, r=False)
clonning repository foo
```

So your parser needs to accept a value.  And you need to pass that value on to your code.  You seem to have read enough of the `argparse` docs to get things like `print_help` and `store_true`, but missed the simpler use of `store` (default) or positional.  Were you trying to do something more sophisticated?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @hpaulj (why isn't an accepted answer?). I guess you found your problem, i.e., store_true does not take argument, then follow hpaulj indications.

In addition, I opened the question because of its title, I was expecting something different such as the following. I wanted to find a way to pass the argparse arguments to a function and possibly modify them with the function arguments. Here is the solution I wrote in case others come looking for this. It may need to be adjusted to account for positional arguments, I also highlight the possible use of vars(args) to get a dictionary from the argparse arguments to compare dict-to-dict with the args_dict:

```
def get_options(args_dict: dict):
    """ get options from command-line,
        update with function args_dict if needed """
    args = get_cmd()  # this is the function taking cmd-line arguments 
    for key, val in args_dict.items():
        if not hasattr(args, key):
            raise AttributeError('unrecognized option: ', key)
        else:
            setattr(args, key, val)
    return(args)
```